# Array of most occurring word in a file separated by newlines.

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

How would I get an array of the top occurring words out of a file separated by newlines (\n)?

Example file:

```
person
person
dog
cat
person
lemon
orange
person
cat
dog
dog
```

The words in the file are in no particular order.

How would I make it behave like the following?

echo $top[0]; //output: person
echo $top[1]; //output: dog
etc...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if two have the same count?

Comment: Good, point... The chance that that would happen in my situation is very small though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$lines = file("theFile.txt");
var_dump(array_count_values($lines));
```

http://php.net/array_count_values

Demo: http://ideone.com/zd82W

To get the first element (word which occurs the most) from the resulting array, you can do this:

```
$arr = array("person", "person", "cat", "dog", "cat");
$newArr = array_count_values($arr);
echo key($newArr); // "person"
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/A0WPa

Comment: That looks like something I can work with, but how would I  be able to retrieve the word with the highest occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use something like this :

- read the file line by line, adding +1 to an array item each time a word is detected, counting for each word how many times it's been seen
- sorting that array.

Not really tested, but something like  this should work, I suppose :

*(should work better than [`array_count_values()`](http://www.php.net/array_count_values) if your file is big : no need to load the whole file into memory)*

```
$words = array();

$f = fopen('your_file', 'r');
while ($line = fgets($f)) {
    $word = trim($line);
    if (isset($words[$words])) {
        $words[$words]++;
    }
    else {
        $words[$words] = 1;
    }
}

asort($words);
```

Now, the first key in the `$words` array is the most used word -- and the corresponding value is the number of times it's been seen in your file.